# What is the best way to restrict login page for authenticated users

Tags: python, django, authentication

I have the following middleware:

```
class SimpleMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response
        self.login_path = '/login/'
        self.home_path = '/'

    def __call__(self, request):

        if request.user.is_authenticated and request.path == self.login_path:
            return redirect(self.home_path)

        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response
```

It is a good idea to redirect any already authed users to home page if they try to reach login page? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not just redirect in the login view?

Comment: Was wondering about code readability

Comment: Yes sure, redirecting authenticated user is good. As long as you provide users with a "logout" link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a redirect_authenticated_user attribute in the LoginView.

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView

class CustomLoginView(LoginView):
    redirect_authenticated_user = True
```